# Reference two columns to one key EF Core

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework-core, c#-6.0

I have a table called `Contact` which has a column called `ContactId`.

I want to create a foreign key on my new table `Advertiser`, but with two different columns - `PrimaryContactId` and `AlternateContactId`.

So I have this code:

```
[ForeignKey(nameof(PrimaryContactId))]
public virtual Contact PrimaryContact { get; set; }

[ForeignKey(nameof(AlternateContactId))]
public virtual Contact AlternateContact { get; set; }

public int PrimaryContactId { get; set; }

public int AlternateContactId { get; set; }

    ...

    builder.HasOne(adv => adv.PrimaryContactId);
    builder.HasOne(adv => adv.AlternateContactId);
```

As you can see I'm not creating two columns, it just one column `ContactId` because it is the id name of key table.

How can I have two columns (`PrimaryContactId` and `AlternateContactId`) referencing the same id (`ContactId`)?

**UPDATE:**

I created columns as:

```
    [ForeignKey(nameof(PrimaryContactId))]
    public virtual Contact PrimaryContact { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(AlternateContactId))]
    public virtual Contact AlternateContact { get; set; }

    public int PrimaryContactId { get; set; }

    public int AlternateContactId { get; set; }
    ...
builder.HasOne(adv => adv.PrimaryContact).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
builder.HasOne(adv => adv.AlternateContact).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

But when I try to insert data into database it throws an error:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Advertisers] ([Name], [AddressId], [PrimaryContactId], [AlternateContactId], [CreatedById])
VALUES ('Samsung', 1, 1, 2, 1), ('Apple', 2, 1, 2, 1)
```

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Advertisers' with
> unique index 'IX_Advertisers_AlternateContactId'. The duplicate key
> value is (2).

Comment: Does you Advertiser table have a unique constraint on the Primary and Alternate contact Id fields?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following:

```
    public int PrimaryContactId { get; set; } 
    public virtual Contact PrimaryContact { get; set; }

    public int AlternateContactId { get; set; } 
    public virtual Contact AlternateContact { get; set; }

    ...

    builder.Entity<YourEntity>.HasOne(adv => adv.PrimaryContact).WithOne().ForeignKey("ContactId");
    builder.Entity<YourEntity>.HasOne(adv => adv.AlternateContact).WithOne().ForeignKey("ContactId");
```